# Есть текстовый файл с которого нужно считать данные и записать в массив c++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Есть текстовый файл с которого нужно считать данные и записать в массив
Например
1 элемент:
Река : Волга
Длина : 3731
Страна : Россия

2 элемент
Река : Вилюй
Длина : 2650
Страна : Россия и т.д
Не знаю как это сделать...

Comment: Ешь слона кусочками.

Comment: первая строка двумерного массива  M[ROW][3] строк содержит  "Река ", "Длина",   "Страна".(а лучше вектор векторов). Другие строки содержат(читаем из файла строку, не сохраняем, игнорируем символ, читаем строку и записываем в первый столбец. Таким же способом записываем и другие столбцы и все остальные строки. 
P. S. Если  речь о массиве, то для получения значения  количества строк _ ROW, нужно считать в файле количество символов 'двоиточие' и разделить на 3, установить позицию чтения на начало файла...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str; 
    ifstream file("main.txt");
    vector <string> vector_str;

    if (!file.is_open())                          // если файл не открыт
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";  // сообщить об этом
    else
    {
        while (file)                             //Считываем полностью файл
        {
            getline(file,str);                   //Записываем строку в str
            vector_str.push_back(str);           //Кидаем строку в вектор
        }

    }
    //Проходим по всему вектору
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_str.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vector_str[i] << endl;          //Выводим содержимое вектора
    }


    file.close();                                //Закрываем файл
    return 0;
}
```

содержимое main.txt

```
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Страна : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Украина : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Польша : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Египет : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Китай : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Страна : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Украина : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Польша : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Египет : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Китай : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Страна : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Украина : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Польша : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Египет : Россия
Река : Волга Длина : 3731 Китай : Россия
```